# Having issue on installing symfony doctrine-migrations-bundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

While I run command `php composer.phar update` it shows the following error. Can anyone help me out for fix it?

> [RuntimeException]
>     An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:
>     Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Fatal error: Call to protected DoctrineORMEntit
>     yManager_000000001f94ab4b000000005d7f3b02e5139c916d21af4abfe5ffe5dd20d49e::__construct() from context 'appDevDebugProjectCon
>     tainer' in /var/www/html/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php:747
>     Stack trace:
>     #0 /var/www/html/app/bootstrap.php.cache(2125): appDevDebugProjectContainer->getDoctrine_Orm_DefaultEntityManagerService()
>     #1 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/ManagerRegistry.php(35): Symfony\Component\DependencyInj
>     ection\Container->get('doctrine.orm.de...')
>     #2 /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/AbstractManagerRegistry.php(231): Symfony\Bridge\Doc
>     trine\ManagerRegistry->getService('doctrine.orm.de...')
>     #3 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/CacheWarmer/ProxyCacheWarmer.php(54): Doctrine\Common\Pe
>     rsistence\AbstractManagerRegistry->getManagers()
>     #4 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Compo in /var/www/html/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on
>     line 747

Comment: Something may be out of sync. Try manually deleting the cache `rm -fr app/cache/*` and re-run the composer command.

Comment: Well, did it. but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

First remove the bundle from your composer.json.

Then try :

```
// replace app by var depending on your symfony version (2 or 3)
rm -Rf app/cache
// clean all your dependencies 
rm -Rf vendor
// reinstall them from your composer.lock
composer install
// install this particular bundle
composer require doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle "^1.0"
```